# How to Fix Jump Height of SKSpriteNode, Collision with SKSpriteNode in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

i am using applyImpluse for fix jump but its take dynamic jump height,

```
   bird.physicsBody  =   SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height / 2)
   bird.physicsBody?.dynamic   =   true
   bird.physicsBody?.friction              =   0.0
   bird.physicsBody?.restitution           =   0.0
   bird.physicsBody?.linearDamping         =   0.0
   bird.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity     =   true
   bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation        =   false
   bird.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask       =   birdCategory
   bird.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask    =   platformCategory 
   bird.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask      =   platformCategory 
   bird.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
   bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 15))
```

//i am using following for jump

```
_bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0,70.0))
```

Comment: did you turn off the friction on your physics world as well?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon bird.physicsBody?.friction  =   0.0 can i set default value ?

Comment: I am also face same issue.